# *ngFor not loading dynamic table headers correctly angular2

Tags: angular, html

I'm having a problem where I am loading dynamic table headers from a server. However, when they load, instead of displaying across the table like they should they stack up in one column.

Here is the html:

```
                 <tr *ngFor="let title of headers">
                 <th class='table-header'>{{title['COLUMN_NAME']}}</th>
             </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody >
                 <tr *ngFor="let item of data | paginate : {itemsPerPage: 25, currentPage: p} ">
                     <td>{{item.ID}}</td>
                     <td>{{item['78d00422ce41_POWER']}}</td>
                     <td>{{item['78d00422ce41_TIME']}}</td>
                     <td>{{item['78d00422821c_POWER']}}</td>
                     <td>{{item['78d00422821c_TIME']}}</td>


             </tr>
             </tbody>
```

heres what the 'headers' array looks like:

```
[  
   {  
      "COLUMN_NAME":"ID"
   },
   {  
      "COLUMN_NAME":"78d00422ce41_POWER"
   },
   {  
      "COLUMN_NAME":"78d00422ce41_TIME"
   },
   {  
      "COLUMN_NAME":"78d00422821c_POWER"
   },
   {  
      "COLUMN_NAME":"78d00422821c_TIME"
   }
]
```

If there's something I'm missing, or that I did wrong, please let me know!

Comment: whats array headers?

Comment: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) Please !!!

Comment: @fatemefazli ill add that to the question

Comment: ```<thead>
    <tr *ngFor="let title of headers">
        <th class='table-header'>{{title['COLUMN_NAME']}}</th>
    </tr>
</thead>``` works fine for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `*ngFor` inside `<th>` tag

```
<th *ngFor="let title of headers" class='table-header'>{{title['COLUMN_NAME']}}</th>
```

Hope this will work for you! :)

Comment: Worked like a charm! Can't believe I didn't think of this first lol

Comment: Cheers! glad to here that :)